# Databricks error when change type column from string to numeric

Tags: python, sql, databricks

I have a error like:

*com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
no viable alternative at input 'alter table x9concsheet5 Add netto_resultaat'(line 1, pos 29)**

when i run this sql command in databricks:

%sql
alter table x9concsheet5 Add netto_resultaat numeric(17,2)

The requirement is to change the column type from string to numeric from the temporary table x9concsheet5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't think you can just "change the data type of an existing column". You'll have to create another column with new type, drop the old one and rename the new to old name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following command to modify the data type

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_col_name new_col_name new_data_type
```

but when are you are tying to modify the column type from string to decimal(17,2), you can do following step ,

1. create a new column with transforming `netto_resultaat` with numeric value from string
2. dropping existing string column

Comment: Thanks for your response. How does the query looks like if i want to create a new column based on a old column ?